# Grouping constraints in domain objects

Tags: grails, constraints, domain-object

Is there a way to group domain object constraints? Something like this:

```
static constraints = {
    personalDetails {
        firstName(nullable: false)
    }
    address {
        street(nullable: false)
    }
}
```

Rich domain plugin does this for NON-domain objects... I want to do this FOR domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

As i know this format does not supported by Grails. May be shared constraints will help you.